# What's the difference between subneting, segmentation and segregation

Tags: vlan

is there a difference between subneting, segmentation and segregation ?

After reading I felt subnetting and segmentation seems to be the same meaning which just divide into smaller network. 
Segregation seem to be a little more advanced in terms of permitting the traffic.

On enterprise level when it comes to creating different VLANs, i believe we should be using segregation more ?

Segregation also seem to be more secure ?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Subneting** is the process of breaking up IP address networks into smaller networks. It is typically used in the context of an ISP providing a company a /16 (for example), which is 65536~ IP Addresses, and that company breaking up those 65k IP addresses into smaller groups for more efficient deployment in their network.

**Segmentation** is the concept of breaking up one larger network into multiple smaller network. It is often associated with [VLANs](http://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vlans/), but doesn't require them. BUT, each new network does require its own IP address range, and therefore also involves the process of **Subneting** described above.

**Segregation** can probably mean different things to different shops, but I've always taken it to mean the concept of placing servers/hosts with different security requirements in different network "zones" so you can apply security policies to traffic flowing to and in between them.

For example, traffic flowing to your web server will be filtered differently than traffic flowing to your database server. As such, it is wise to put your web server in a different network than your database server, and also ideally separate those networks with some sort of Firewall or security device.

Segregation will involve creating different/isolated networks, which might involve Segmentation, which will therefore also involve Subnetting.

Answer (score 0):

I think subneting is the logical implementation of the segregation.

Comment: Segregation is generally for isolation purposes, tytpically to keep secrets or separate production from developmenr. In a co-located environment, this is expected. Subnetting alone will allow routing. Segregated networks are generally isolated.